# how to get cloudwatch metrics from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to write my own tools for AWS monitoring calling AWS api from console and later build some graphs.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name MemoryUtilization --start-time 2022-11-19 --end-time 2022-11-21 --period 3600 --dimensions Name=ClusterName,Value=<mycluster> --dimensions Name=ServiceName,Value=<service-name> --namespace ECS/ContainerInsights --statistics Average
```

and this is always reporting 0 datapoint, whereas I can see that there are metrics collected in the console.

what is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1):

issue was the multiple dimensions args are given by just separating then with a space, instead of adding another `--dimensions`

so this worked.

```
echo running $metric on $ServiceName
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name $metric \
    --start-time $start_time --end-time $end_time \
    --period $period \
    --dimensions Name=ClusterName,Value=<my-cluster> Name=ServiceName,Value=$ServiceName \
    --namespace $namespace \
    --statistics $statistics  --output text  > $ServiceName-$metric-$now.csv
```